# Buscador en tiempo real con VueJS y Laravel

Tags: laravel, vue.js

**Si hay otra forma de hacer mi buscador comenten el aporte, gracias.**

Necesito solucionar esto con rapidez, ya que solo 2 errores me detienen de terminar.
Repito. Si hay otra forma de hacer el buscador pero que mas o menos sea por 2 partes. El form del buscador en un archivo y el otro donde estén solo los resultados. Algo asi como lo tengo.

Estoy haciendo el apartado del buscador en VueJS y Laravel, pero tengo un problema que no me deja avanzar en las demás secciones. El buscador abre y todo pero cuando escribo solo manda la primera letra o 2 pero no todas como esta en esta imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ya después de eso me muestra el siguiente error en consola:

```
Uncaught (in promise) NavigationDuplicated: Avoided redundant navigation to current location: "/search?q=th"
```

Ahora mostrando mi código del buscador:

```
<template>
  <div class="form_MCycW">
    <form autocomplete="off" @sumbit.prevent>
      <label class="visuallyhidden" for="search">Search</label>

      <div class="field_2KO5E">
        <input id="search" ref="input" v-model.trim="query" name="search" type="text" placeholder="Search for a movie, tv show or person..." @keyup="goToRoute" @blur="unFocus">

        <button v-if="showButton" type="button" aria-label="Close" @click="goBack">
          <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="15" height="15" viewBox="0 0 15 15"><g fill="none" stroke="#fff" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-width="1.5"><path d="M.75.75l13.5 13.5M14.25.75L.75 14.25"/></g></svg>
        </button>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  import { mapState } from 'vuex';

  export default {
    data() {
      return {
        query: this.$route.query.q ? this.$route.query.q : ''
      }
    },

    computed: {
       showButton() {
       return this.$route.name === 'search';
    },
    ...mapState({
      search: state => state.event.fromPage
    })
  },

  mounted() {
    this.$refs.input.focus();
  },

  methods: {
    goToRoute() {
      if (this.query) {
        this.$router.push({
          name: 'search',
          query: { q: this.query },
        });
      } else {
        this.$router.push({
          path: this.fromPage,
        });
      }
    },

    goBack() {
      this.query = '';

      this.$router.push({
        path: '/',
      });
    },

    unFocus (e) {
      if (this.$route.name !== 'search') {
        const target = e.relatedTarget;

        if (!target || !target.classList.contains('search-toggle')) {
          this.query = '';
          this.$store.commit('closeSearch');
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

En mi seccion de rutas está definida de la siguiente manera:

```
{
  name: 'search',
  path: '/search',
  component: require('../views/' + themeName + '/control/search/index').default,
  meta: {
    title: 'Search'
  }
}
```

Se supone que tiene que ser un buscador en tiempo real.
Agradecería de su ayuda para solucionar este problema.

Este es el archivo donde mustra las busquedas:

```
<template>
  <main class="main">
    <div class="listing">
      <div class="listing__head"><h2 class="listing__title">{{ title }}</h2></div>
      <div class="listing__items">
        <div class="card" v-for="(item, index) in data.data" :key="index">
          <router-link v-if="item.type == 'series'" :to="{ name: 'show-serie', params: { id: item.id }}" class="card__link">
            <div class="card__img lazyloaded"><img class="lazyload image_183rJ" :src="'/_assets/img/covers/posters/' + item.poster" :alt="item.name"></div>
            <h2 class="card__name">{{ item.name }}</h2>
            <div class="card__rating">
              <div class="card__stars"><div :style="{width: item.rate * 10 + '%'}"></div></div>
              <div class="card__vote">{{ item.rate }}</div>
            </div>
          </router-link>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="listing__nav"></div>
    </div>
  </main>
</template>
<script>
  import { mapState } from 'vuex';
  let fromPage = '/';

  export default {
    name: "search",

    metaInfo: {
      bodyAttrs: {
        class: 'page page-search'
      }
    },

    computed: {
      ...mapState({
        data: state => state.search.data,
        loading: state => state.search.loading
      }),

      query() {
        return this.$route.query.q ? this.$route.query.q : '';
      },

      title() {
        return this.query ? `Results For: ${this.query}` : '';
      },
    },

    async asyncData ({ query, error, redirect }) {
      try {
        if (query.q) {
          this.$store.dispatch("GET_SEARCH_LIST", query.q);
        } else {
          redirect('/');
        }
      } catch {
        error({ message: 'Page not found' });
      }
    },

    mounted () {
      this.$store.commit('openSearch');
      this.$store.commit('setFromPage', fromPage);
    },

    beforeRouteLeave (to, from, next) {
      const search = document.getElementById('search');

      next();

      if (search && search.value.length) {
        this.$store.commit('closeSearch');
      }
    }
  };
</script>
```

En la parte del `mounted` estaba esto lo que daba las consultas que buscaba pero creo que no es la manera de hacerlo.

```
if (this.data.length == 0 || this.data === null) {
   this.$store.dispatch("GET_SEARCH_LIST", this.query);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

por fin descubrí la respuesta y solo tenia que poner el el `beforerouteupdate` el método de la consulta y ahi seguir con la programación.

Este es el code:

```
beforeRouteUpdate (to, from, next) {
  next();
  this.getResults();
},

beforeRouteLeave (to, from, next) {
  const search = document.getElementById('search');

  next();

  if (search && search.value.length) {
    this.$store.commit('closeSearch');
  }
},

methods: {
  async getResults() {
    if (!this.query.length) {
      this.item = null;
      return;
    }

    const data = this.$store.dispatch("GET_SEARCH_LIST", this.query);
    
    if (!data.total_results) {
      this.items = null;
      return;
    }

    this.item = item;
  }
}
```